# equals() and hashCode() in Java LinkedHashMap and tree map?

Tags: java, collections, treemap, linkedhashmap

overriding `equals() and hashCode()` is not required for `TreeMap` while required for `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap`.

`TreeMap` works on implementation provided by `Comparable` or `Comparator` `interface` when using user created Classes as `Key` for `Map`

Is this correct?

Comment: Your second statement is wrong. `TreeMap` also should obey the general contract of Map and then on top of it, Comparable and Comparator comes.

Comment: but when trying to debug the program code .... Its never going inside     equals() method .... Tried to achieve Collision condition as well .. by returning same int value every time ... none of the case its reaching to equals().

Answer (score 1):

Internally `TreeMap` use only `compare` function for keys.

The method `containsValue` use internally `equals`. So it is necessary to redefine `equals` for values, not for keys.

`HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` use internally `equals` and `hashCode` on the keys. So you need to redefine it for your key class. As for TreeMap also `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` uses `equals` for the values. So it is necessary to redefine equals for values.

Answer (score 1):

To answer such questions it's much better to read the documentation instead of performing a test. Test shows nothing. Even if you see that methods are not called, it does not mean that they will not be called in further Java versions or using another JDK vendor. Or probably these methods could be called when performing some other operations with your map.

In this particular case the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) says the following:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, **must be consistent with** `equals` if this sorted map is to correctly implement the `Map` interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of consistent with `equals`.) This is so because the `Map` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal. The behavior of a sorted map *is* well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with `equals`; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Map` interface.

Emphasis mine.

So according to the last sentence the `TreeMap` will be fully functional if you not define the `equals` method for the keys, but it will violate the contract of the `Map` interface. For example, [`Map.containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) contract is the following:

> Returns `true` if this map contains a mapping for the specified key. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key `k` such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`.

So this would be wrong if you use the `TreeMap` with keys having inconsistent `equals` implementation. If you pass your map to some method which assumes that the passed map follows the contract, then that method may work incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I always follow a simple recipe: for all map implementations, I always override `hashCode()` and `equals()`. If the map is also a `SortedMap`, I also override `compare()` or implement a `Comparator` (in both cases the comparison must be consistent with `equals()`, which means that the result of the comparison must return `0` if the elements being compared are actually equal).

This recipe allows me to use whichever map implementation I feel is the most appropriate for the specific problem I'm tackling, and it even allows me to use different map implementations for the same key class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i am correct (Please Correct me if I am wrong)... Check Following Code -

```
In this following code `equals()` and `hashCode()` is never get called , so in `TreeMap` does these never gets called in `TreeMap` ?? Or something wrong I have Done ???? its never printing `inside hashCode()` `inside equals()`

package Map;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class HashCodeEqualsTester {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Car car1 = new Car("788");
        Driver driver1 = new Driver("Kevin");

        Car car2 = new Car("656");
        Driver driver2 = new Driver("Bob");

        Car car3 = new Car("343");
        Driver driver3 = new Driver("Stuart");

        Map<Car, Driver> myMap = new TreeMap<Car, Driver>();
        // Map<Car, Driver> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<Car, Driver>();
        // Map<Car, Driver> myMap = new HashMap<Car, Driver>(); 
        // try to run these 3 one at a time and see how does it behave 

        myMap.put(car1, driver1);
        myMap.put(car2, driver2);
        myMap.put(car3, driver3);



        System.out.println(myMap);
    }
}

class Car implements Comparable{
    private String carNumber;

    public Car (String carNumber){
        this.carNumber = carNumber;
    }
    public String getCarNumber() {
        return carNumber;
    }
    public void setCarNumber(String carNumber) {
        this.carNumber = carNumber;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return ("Car Number : " + carNumber);
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println("Inside hashCode()");
        int hashCode = 1;
        hashCode = hashCode * this.getCarNumber().hashCode();
        System.out.println("For Car Number : " + this.getCarNumber() + " hashcode is : " + hashCode);
        //return hashCode;
        return 1000;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        System.out.println("Inside equals()");
        if (!(o instanceof Car)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Car car = (Car) o;
            return (this.getCarNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(car.getCarNumber()));
        }
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Car car = (Car) o;

        return (this.getCarNumber().compareTo(car.getCarNumber()));
    }
}

class Driver {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return (this.getName() + " ");
    }
    public Driver(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```